# New graphics card - System shuts down when gaming

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I bought a new Graphic card yesterday, a Geforce GTX 970, and I swapped it with my old one. and I realize now that maybe I should have done some more research about it beforehand, as it seems there is more to it, than just checking if the motherboard has the proper PCI Expresse connector. I even had to cut some metal because the card wouldn't fit in the case :P

The problem is that when I start some games, the system resets completely. I suspect it has to do with the power. When I took out my old graphic card, I saw that the power was coming from a "V cable" with a 6-pin connector on one side and 2 "peripheral" on the other side. Kinda like this one.

[image]

And actually only one of the 2 "peripheral" connectors only one was actually plugged. This had worked with my old card without a cinch in the past, so I naively thought it would work as well on my new graphic card.

Surprise came when I saw that in my new card, there was a 6-pin connector next to another 8 pin connector. I connected the 6-pin as it was with the old card, and the system was working alright, except when I started a game. In that moment, the computer did a hard reset.

I thought I was lacking power, so I tried connecting the other cables, but here is the problem:

I have 2 "V cables", one for a 6 pin and one for a 8 pin, that means that I have 4 "peripheral connectors", but from my Power Supply come out just 3 peripheral connectors. I tries connecting just 3 of them but it is still not enough. The computers keeps resetting.

So my questios are:

- **Is my analysis of the problem false?**
- **Do I need a new power supply with more connectors?**

**UPDATE**

Here are some of my system specs

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also I do not think it is included in the screenshots, but **my PSU is 500 Watts**

Comment: I think your GPU isn't getting enough power - the 970 is pretty beefy and you definitely need *both* connectors to supply enough power. Might help to state your *full* system configuration to work out if your PSU is powerful enough, or find a power supply calculator online and plug in your system specs.

Answer (score 0):

Your new graphics card needs more power than the old one. I suspect the reason your PC is resetting is a lack of power.

You need something like a 500-600W power supply to run the GTX 970 reliably on an otherwise standard system.

Further reading/source: [forum post on TomsHardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2307222/gtx-970-minimum-power-supply-requirement.html)

Comment: I actually believe my PSU has 500W

Comment: Could you provide an answer to the 2nd question?

Comment: Yes, I believe you need a new power supply. The issue is the power, that your PSU can deliver to your graphics card. And it seems like it's not able to deliver enough through your 5V molex plugs (the white ones on your picture). So you need to either move your molex plugs around so that your graphics card get power off of two different rails (sets of wires going out of your PSU) or get a new PSU (preferably one that has the needed outputs for your GFX so you dont need to get power from the 5V rails, as in your current setup).